# RabbitMQ headers Exchange routing to all queues instead of matching headers

Tags: rabbitmq

I have an Exchange defined as a `headers` exchange.  I've then bound queues like so:

[image]

When I publish the message as shown in the image, the message winds up going to all of the bound queues.  My expectation (based on the header binding) was that the message would **only** go to the event.retry.fail queue.

Am I misunderstanding how header exchanges work?  Does the header exchange only look for the presence of the header and **NOT** look at the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after further experimentation, I found that it had to do with the name of my header.  "x-" prefix must be reserved for RabbitMQ -- just a guess.

By removing the "x-" prefix and just using a header of "rqcm-retry" everything started working as expected.

Comment: [You are correct](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-headers): "For 'any' and 'all', headers beginning with the string `x-` will not be used to evaluate matches."